# Does this negative unit testing make sense

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have tests like that. Negative unit testing.

Does this test make sense? Is it not better to test only the expected exceptional scenarios?

```
[Test]
public void Get_Root_Units_By_Non_Existing_TemplateId()
{
// ARRANGE
ITemplateUnitDataProvider provider = new TemplateUnitDataProvider(_connectionString);
int templateId = -1;

// ACT
var units = provider.GetRootUnits(templateId);

// ASSERT
Assert.IsNotNull(units);
Assert.Count(0, units);           
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this test makes sense. You are checking that the SUT (Subject Under Test) returns an empty array if it hasn't found any records matching the input parameter.

Comment: +1. Testing expected behaviour when encountering unexpected, invalid or pathological (if that is indeed the word I am looking for) inputs is important, too. You don't want your program to crash or loop indefinitely because of this.

Comment: Would you say that any negative input value has the same importance than any other negative value?

Comment: No, but the same probably also holds for "positive" (correct) input values.

Comment: @Darin Does this negative fail test also makes sense to you in the context that a templateId MUST exist else the related units could never have added. I mean surely for a templateId -1 there will never exist units because a negative identity column (TemplateId) can not work. My concern seems to be different to yours.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, unit tests are used to check your method's correctness. Handling incorrect input correctly is also something you want to test for.

Unit tests are meant to give you a sense of security about your code, so handling invalid input is certainly something I would test.

Answer (score 0):

One good reason to wite fail test is any unit test is better than no unit test

writing fail test lets you know your system well what it should fail on else you have some other scenario's that you are not aware of

Comment: Not sure I agree. Redundant tests are just technical debt. Incorrect tests are even worse.

Comment: @Thilo I kind of agree with u but in my opinion writing fail test you know your system well what it should fail on

Comment: I agree with you that fail tests are important, too. I disagree with the reasoning you gave. That's like saying 80 lines of code are better than no code. It seems that would depend on what that code does and how it does it.

Comment: @Thilo I am trying to cover scenarios that must fail on certain condition as fail unit test